# Dealing twelve cards from a deck of 40

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

We have 40 cards. A, B, C extract resp. 5,4,3 cards. How many extractions can we make in which A and B don't extract swords while C extract at least 2? Solution: $C_{30,5}\cdot C_{25,4}\cdot C_{10,2}\cdot C_{29,1}$.

I wrote: $C_{30,5}\cdot C_{25,4}\cdot C_{10,2}\cdot C_{21,1}+C_{30,5}\cdot C_{25,4}\cdot C_{10,3}$. Why is my solution wrong?

Comment: at least... what? :)

Comment: I've just changed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reference to a $40$-card deck with swords as a suit means this is a Spanish deck with $10$ each of swords,  cups, coins and clubs, not the "standard" (French) $52$-card deck.

Your solution is the correct one, distinguishing between two-sword and three-sword cases. The given solution overcounts those cases where C's hand is all swords: it counts picking ($\{2,3\}$ and then $4$ of swords) and ($\{4,3\}$ and then $2$ of swords) as distinct, when they are not.

Comment: For me their solution takes into account that surely C extracts 2 swords and the third card he extracts can be a sword or any other card (and that's the reason of 29)

Comment: @Veronica Yes, but what if C picks the 2 and 3 of swords and then the 4 of swords, or the 3 and 4 and then the 2? The given solution treats these cases as distinct, when they are not.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  The comment you wrote should be part of your answer.